# PHP code not updating form values to database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a sample data in my database that I am trying to override with my data in a form submission with a primary key PageID set to 0, my query to my knowledge is correct, I have no errors upon submission just no data going into the database. Here is the entire PHP document.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
  $pageid = 0; 

 $dbc = @mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'elinksw_ju1ez', '*******', 'elinksw_ju1ez') OR die ('<p class="error">Cannot connect to the database.</body></html>');

 $q = "UPDATE tblContent SET PageHeading='$_POST[PageHeading]' ,SubHeading='$_POST[SubHeading]' ,Content='$_POST[Content]' ,PageTitle='$_POST[PageTitle]' ,MetaDescription='$_POST[MetaDescription]' ,MetaKeywords='$_POST[MetaKeywords]'  WHERE PageID='$pageid'";
 $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
mysqli_close($dbc);

 }
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./includes/adminStyle.css">
<title>Administration - Edit content</title>
</head>

<body>
<header>
<h1>Edit Content</h1>
<h2>Welcome Administrator</h2>
</header>

<nav>
<a href="admin.php" class="myButton">Manage Homepage</a><br>
<a href="admin.php" class="myButton">Manage Products</a><br>
<a href="admin.php" class="myButton">Manage Contacts</a><br>
</nav>

<section>
<h2>Manage Homepage</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

<table width="300" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Page Heading:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="PageHeading"></td> </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sub Heading:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="SubHeading"></td>  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Page Title:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="PageTitle"></td>   </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>MetaDescription:</td>
        <td><textarea style="width:300px;" cols="55" rows="5" name="MetaDescription"></textarea></td>   </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>MetaKeywords:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="MetaKeywords"></td>    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content:</td>
        <td><textarea style="width:300px;" cols="55" rows="5" name="Content"></textarea></td>   </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="update" value = "Update Database"></td>  </tr>

</section>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Here is the table in the database
[image]

Comment: have you tried echoing any errors - ie. `$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));`?

Comment: You should have `$_POST['PageHeading']` instead of `$_POST[PageHeading]`. Also, your query is vulnerable to sql injections.

Comment: I have checked for errors and echoed out results,  nothing shows. So I thought maybe it was a connection problem, rumbled with that had the connection read successful is connection was establish and it was. It's like no data is coming out or reading to this database.

Comment: If any of your `$_POST` values have single quotes `'`, then your query will fail. At a minimum you want to use [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) and better would be to use prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @kidA if OP adds the single quotes, they will also need to add brackets `{}` as they would get a syntax error inside double quotes - `{$_POST['PageHeading']}`

Comment: It would be helpful if you include which tests have you performed (which strings you used, etcetera) and a description of your table (`DESCRIBE tblContent`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your code is dangerous, is vulnerable to Injection attacks, you have to filter and escape your $_POST variables (http://corpocrat.com/2009/07/28/filtering-escaping-post-data-from-injection-attacks)

A quick & dirty solution to grasp what's going on would involve:

```
$PageHeading = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['PageHeading']);
$subHeading = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['SubHeading']);
$Content = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['Content']);
$PageTitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['PageTitle']);
$MetaDescription = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['MetaDescription']);
$MetaKeywords = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['MetaKeywords']);
$q = "UPDATE tblContent SET PageHeading='$PageHeading' ,SubHeading='$SubHeading' ,Content='$Content' ,PageTitle='$PageTitle' ,MetaDescription='$MetaDescription' ,MetaKeywords='$MetaKeywords'  WHERE PageID='$pageid'";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q) or die(mysqli_error($dbc)); //remove this on production
```

Comment: OP's `mysqli_*` does not match with your `mysql_*`/`mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` requires the db link as the 1st param - `mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['PageHeading']);` as apposed to `mysql_real_escape_string` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: ouch.... too used to the OO version $dbc->real_escape_string($string); :( thanks again

Comment: I'm still wondering if this is an actual solution for her problem. Would this work even if the strings were entered without quotes?

Comment: I've been trying so hard trying to fix the query I haven't really worked on the rest and overlooked the simple problem. Trying to keep it simplistic until I had it inserting values so I knew what wasn't working. But I tested this and it worked perfectly, so much thanks. With my query it was the single quotes. PageHeading='$_POST[PageHeading]' should have been PageHeading=$_POST['PageHeading']. Look that over too many times. ty ty

Comment: Hi @AlejandroIván, her query was not working indeed because of no quoting $_POST keys, but risk of Injection was too evident that I couldn't simply give an "quote your $_POST keys" answer...